# Ubuntu 22.04 trackpad gestures not working after installing Nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, touchpad, multi-touch

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and installed the Nvidia drivers recommended for the graphics card (GTX 1650). After the reboot, the trackpad cannot detect multi-finger touch gestures. I have tried:

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001F99sv000017AAsd00003A42bc03sc00i00 
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : TU117M
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-510 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-510-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-515-server - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

I have installed the recommended driver using `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` command and rebooted my system to find out that the trackpad gestures are no longer detected. Is there a way around to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was caused by logging to X-org (which doesn't support gestures) and not wayland X-server.

You can configure this on the login, just before entering your password, there's a setting icon in the lower right corner. Choose "Wayland" or "Ubuntu on wayland".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).